# ADO restricted table name

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I have to connect to a table called "***DATABASE***" which seems to be not allowed. Is there a workaround without changing the table name?

```
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    RawData = IIf(SelectedRawDromXL <> "", SelectedRawDromXL, SelectedRawFile1)
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & RawData & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="
    Set objRecordsetraw = New ADODB.Recordset
    ggg = "DATABASE"
    objRecordsetraw.Open ggg, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

[image]

Comment: `ggg` should be either a valid SQL-string like `SELECT * FROM tblName` or the name of a table resp. query which exists in the MS Access database file. What is the error message you get? And at which line?

Comment: So, I guess you get the error message at the line `objRecordsetraw.Open ggg, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`. The reason is the `ggg` does not contain a name of a table or query in your MS Access database, or does it?

Answer (score 2):

In case `DATABASE` is a table my suggestion would be

```
ggg = "[DATABASE]"
objRecordsetraw.Open ggg, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

**PS 1**: `adLockOptimistic + adCmdTable` is not working in my environment. I get RTE 3001 when running the line `objRecordsetraw.Open ggg, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic + adCmdTable`.

**PS 2**: This is probably the cause of the issue
[List of reserved words in Access 2002 and in later versions of Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words)

Comment: That is also only working with brackets added to `DATABASE`.

Comment: I'd just say it is working and right now I do not understand why a table like `Customer` is working without brackets and `DATABASE` only with brackets just because DATABASE is a reserved name in Access.

Comment: It's because defining only a table name is silly, and ADO just prepends `SELECT * FROM ` to it (view `objRecordsetraw.Source`). One should really only use the table name in conjunction with `adCmdTableDirect`, where it actually opens up a different recordset type with different features.